# Eyeshot PolyRegion2D.Union with tolerance

Tags: eyeshot

I would like to join two polygons which are nearly tangent. The problem is that the library that I use does not allow to specify a tolerance.

The method I tried to use is `PolyRegion2D.Union`. The result I would like to obtain should be a single `PolyRegion2D`, no union is performed instead.

This is what I tried:

```
Polygon2D pa = new Polygon2D(new Point2D[] {
    new Point2D(1.15938971595503,-0.199967078272286),
    new Point2D(1.52634922341708,-0.420128484528485),
    new Point2D(1.70641430562392,-0.120000722926738),
    new Point2D(1.17299051700752,0.200032892324767),
    new Point2D(0.561190378505281,0.200032892324767),
    new Point2D(0.561190378505281,-0.199967078272286),
    new Point2D(1.15938971595503,-0.199967078272286)
});
PolyRegion2D a = new PolyRegion2D(new Polygon2D[] { pa });

Polygon2D pb = new Polygon2D(new Point2D[] {
    new Point2D(2.15660570919657,-0.39009846249557),
    new Point2D(1.70641430562392,-0.120000887257862),
    new Point2D(1.52634925853194,-0.420128484528485),
    new Point2D(1.97654066210459,-0.690226059766193),
    new Point2D(2.15660570919657,-0.39009846249557)
});
PolyRegion2D b = new PolyRegion2D(new Polygon2D[] { pb });

PolyRegion2D[] ab = PolyRegion2D.Union(a, b);

Assert.AreEqual(1, ab.Length);
```

I tried also to convert the `PolyRegion2D`s to `Region`, specifing various deviations on the `Regen` method, but I obtain the same result.

The only workaround that I've found is to `Offset` the regions by some amount before the union, but it seems overwhelming.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your derivation on Regen should only affect curves if i am not mistaken, so it shouldn't affect anything in your case since you use sharp lines.

**Offset is the way to go for the geometry union.**

That's how the maths work. Projecting vectors, checking for intersection doesn't work by magic. Without offset you would have to invent a way to do geometry unions like you would want.